# How to limit the number of port forwarding connections - ssh

Tags: ssh

I have a user on my linux server which is used for proxy. Currently the shell access and a lot of other features are disabled and the following command will be used on it:

```
ssh proxy-user@server -D 1080 -N
```

However recently I decided to put a limit on the number of simultaneous connections.

I've tried `limits.conf` and `MaxSessions`, but none of them can deal with the `ssh -N` argument. They won't count these types of connections for the limit.

Is there anyway for me to limit the number of connections that are only using port forwarding (using the `-N` argument)?

**Notes:**

- No I can't use a socks server such as dante
- I can't limit the total number of connections for all the users because I don't want to apply the limit for other users
- Here is the current limitations for the proxy user:

```
Match User proxy-user
   AllowTcpForwarding yes
   X11Forwarding no
   PermitTunnel no
   GatewayPorts no
   AllowAgentForwarding no
   PasswordAuthentication yes
   ForceCommand echo 'This account can only be used for socks proxy'
```

Comment: AFAIK the only native control the openssh server gives you is to either completely allow/prohibit port forwarding  with the `AllowTcpForwarding` directive but there is nothing to control the number of connections when that is allowed.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1764623/limiting-ssh-tunnel-users-maxlogins